# Dynamically update existing table record with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm building an application in which there is a sign-up form. When I click `submit`, a new table row is dynamically created and the table is saved in local storage. `Edit` and `Delete` buttons are appended with the table row. When I click on `Edit`, data in **td** having classes name, mail, mob, add should populate name, email, mobile no. and address fields in the sign up form respectively. Furthermore when I submit, the changes should be updated in the same table row whose edit button I had clicked.

But instead of that, a new record is created. I'm attempting to pass the row `id` to the add function in my code and this is what I have done so far.

```
function save(){
    var taskList = [];
    $("#saveTable tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
         var task = {};
        var currentRow  = $(this).closest("tr");
        task.name    = currentRow.find('.name').text();
        task.mail     = currentRow.find(".mail").text();
        task.mob =    currentRow.find(".mob").text(); 
        task.add = currentRow.find(".add").text(); 
        task.Country = currentRow.find(".country").text();
        task.State = currentRow.find(".state").text(); 
        taskList.push(task);
    });
    saveObject("tasks",taskList);   
}
function saveObject(recordKey,jsObject){
    var objectAsString = JSON.stringify(jsObject);
    localStorage.setItem(recordKey,objectAsString);
}
function load(){
    var taskList = loadObject("tasks");
    for(var index=0; taskList && index<taskList.length; ++index){
        this.add(taskList[index]);
    }

}
 function loadObject(recordKey){
    var objectAsString = localStorage.getItem(recordKey);
    return JSON.parse(objectAsString);
}

function add(taskObject,index){
    if(index){
        console.log(index);
        var update = $('#saveTable tbody').find('tr').eq(index);


    }
    var newTR = $("<tr class='child'></tr>");
    var newName = $("<td class='name'></td>");
    var newMail = $("<td class='mail'></td>");
    var newMob = $("<td class='mob'></td>");
    var newAdd = $("<td class='add'></td>");
    var newCountry = $("<td class='country'></td>");
    var newState = $("<td class='state'></td>");
    var edit = $("<input class='button_ed' type='submit' value='Edit'/>");
    var del = $("<input class='button_del' type='submit' value='Delete'/>");

    $(newTR).append($(newName).text(taskObject.name));
    $(newTR).append($(newMail).text(taskObject.mail));
    $(newTR).append($(newMob).text(taskObject.mob));
    $(newTR).append($(newAdd).text(taskObject.add));
    $(newTR).append($(newCountry).text(taskObject.Country));
    $(newTR).append($(newState).text(taskObject.State));
    $(newTR).append($(edit)).append($(del));
    $("#saveTable tbody").append($(newTR));
    $(edit).on("click",function myEdit(){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.value=="Edit") {
            this.value="Save";
         var ed = this.closest("tr");
         $('#contact_name').val($(ed).children("td.name").text());
         $('#contact_email').val($(ed).children("td.mail").text());
         $('#contact_mob').val($(ed).children("td.mob").text());
         $('#contact_address').val($(ed).children("td.add").text());
         $('#contact_name').addClass("valid");
         $('#contact_email').addClass("valid");
         $('#contact_mob').addClass("valid");
         $('#contact_address').addClass("valid");
         //collect table row id in variable and pass it to add function
         index = ed.rowIndex;
         //console.log(index);
         save();
        }
    });
    $(del).on("click",function myDel(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        save();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's save() do? How are you saving the data to the db? It seems somewhere in the $(edit).on('click') function there should be a put method call to the db.

Comment: I am saving the data in local storage

Comment: I have added the code for save function for your reference.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're using the two load functions but it looks like you're getting the selected row in the edit function then calling save(), and then doing the same thing in the save() function, which calls saveObject() and that's saving it to the local storage. Inside the edit() function don't call save()...instead do a local storage get by lets say email address or something in there unique to find the record. Once you get the record from local, then do the set with the current row values in the edit() function. Your loadObject() function seems to be doing this already.

Comment: I wouldn't focus on trying to get the rowId in the array unless there are no other unique values. If you want to use rowId, you'll have to add it to tasklist[] such as:

task.id  = currentRow.rowIndex;